# Next-Auth in App Dir with Prisma on Supabase Postgres and SendGrid EmailProvider server throwing [MISSING_ADAPTER_METHODS_ERROR]

Tags: next.js, prisma, next-auth, supabase, next.js13

I am using Next-Auth with PrismaAdapter, Prisma connected to a Supabase Postgres database in a Next.js 13 App Dir project. I also have a SendGrid connection which I am unsure whether I configured right, there aren't any guides on this particular implementation as far as I could research.

Not sure if it'll help but it's 100% not a problem with my PrismaClient setup - I baselined my database and migrated my current schema to the db correctly, then generated a client.

With my current code below, I am getting the following error:

```
[next-auth][error][MISSING_ADAPTER_METHODS_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#missing_adapter_methods_error Required adapter methods were missing: createVerificationToken, useVerificationToken, getUserByEmail MissingAdapterMethods [MissingAdapterMethodsError]: Required adapter methods were missing: createVerificationToken, useVerificationToken, getUserByEmail
    at assertConfig (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/lib/assert.js:71:20)
    at AuthHandler (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js:90:54)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async NextAuthRouteHandler (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:49:30)
    at async NextAuth._args$ (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:83:24)
    at async eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:265:37) {
  code: 'MISSING_ADAPTER_METHODS_ERROR'
}
```

**[...nextauth].ts**

```
import { prisma } from '@/lib/prisma';
import { PrismaAdapter } from '@next-auth/prisma-adapter';
import NextAuth, { type NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth';
import EmailProvider from 'next-auth/providers/email';

const HOST = process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_HOST;
if (!HOST) throw new Error('EMAIL_SERVER_HOST is not set');
const PORT = Number(process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_PORT);
if (!PORT) throw new Error('EMAIL_SERVER_PORT is not set');
const USER = process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_USER;
if (!USER) throw new Error('EMAIL_SERVER_USER is not set');
const PASSWORD = process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_PASSWORD;
if (!PASSWORD) throw new Error('EMAIL_SERVER_PASSWORD is not set');
const FROM = process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_FROM;
if (!FROM) throw new Error('EMAIL_FROM is not set');

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt',
  },
  providers: [
    EmailProvider({
      server: {
        host: HOST,
        port: PORT,
        auth: {
          user: USER,
          pass: PASSWORD,
        },
      },
      from: FROM,
    }),
  ],

  callbacks: {
    session: ({ session, token }) => {
      console.log('Session Callback', { session, token });
      return {
        ...session,
        user: {
          ...session.user,
          id: token.id,
          randomKey: token.randomKey,
        },
      };
    },
    jwt: ({ token, user }) => {
      console.log('JWT Callback', { token, user });
      if (user) {
        const u = user as unknown as any;
        return {
          ...token,
          id: u.id,
          randomKey: u.randomKey,
        };
      }
      return token;
    },
  },
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

**prisma.ts**

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

// PrismaClient is attached to the `global` object in development to prevent
// exhausting your database connection limit.
//
// Learn more:
// https://pris.ly/d/help/next-js-best-practices

const globalForPrisma = global as unknown as { prisma: PrismaClient };

export const prisma =
  globalForPrisma.prisma ||
  new PrismaClient({
    log: ['query'],
  });

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') globalForPrisma.prisma = prisma;
```

I also wonder if my Provider wrapper has the right approach:

**layout.tsx**

```
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html className='h-full antialiased' lang='en'>
      <head>
        <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: modeScript }} />
        <link
          rel='alternate'
          type='application/rss+xml'
          href={`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SITE_URL}/rss/feed.xml`}
        />
        <link
          rel='alternate'
          type='application/feed+json'
          href={`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SITE_URL}/rss/feed.json`}
        />
      </head>
      <body className='flex flex-col h-full bg-zinc-50 dark:bg-black'>
        <div className='fixed inset-0 flex justify-center sm:px-8'>
          <div className='flex w-full max-w-7xl lg:px-8'>
            <div className='w-full bg-white ring-1 ring-zinc-100 dark:bg-zinc-900 dark:ring-zinc-300/20' />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='relative'>
          <Header />
          <Providers>{children}</Providers>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

**providers.tsx**

```
'use client';

import { SessionProvider } from 'next-auth/react';

type Props = {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
};

export const Providers = ({ children }: Props) => {
  return <SessionProvider>{children}</SessionProvider>;
};
```

Like I said, above code is what I've tried and it throws the MISSING_ADAPTER_METHODS_ERROR.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out `Nextauthjs` has been moved to [Authjs](https://authjs.dev/getting-started/providers/email-tutorial). (Note: at the time I am writing this the site was still under development and lacked proper explanation).

If anyone is facing the error with `prisma`:

```
MISSING_ADAPTER_METHODS_ERROR` and `Required adapter methods were missing: createVerificationToken, useVerificationToken, getUserByEmail
```

The solution would be to :

1. Install `@auth/prisma-adapter`

   ```
    npm install @prisma/client @auth/prisma-adapter
    npm install prisma --save-dev
   ```
2. Use the new prisma client as the adapter

   ```
    import NextAuth, { type NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
    import EmailProvider from "next-auth/providers/email"
    import { PrismaAdapter } from "@auth/prisma-adapter"
    import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client"

    // create a prisma client if one doesn't already exist
    const prisma = new PrismaClient()

    export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
      adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
      secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
      providers: [
        EmailProvider({
          server: {
            host: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_HOST,
            port: Number(process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_PORT),
            auth: {
              user: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_USER,
              pass: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_PASSWORD,
            },
          },
          from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
        }),
      ],
    };

    const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

    export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
   ```